# Can't stop Azure AD Connect Service

Tags: active-directory, azure, entra-id

Have an on-prem server for Azure AD Connect service. Today I noticed that a Delta Import (we run a delta sync on the scheduler every 30 mins) was In-Progress with no estimated end time. It is sitting like that until the next scheduled sync, then it terminates it and starts the cycle over again.

I think I have pinpointed the issue (it's with a change to the ADSYNC account) but I am unable to stop the AD Connect service to change the run profile properties.

I have:
- tried to stop the run profile from MSIClient (it just saying stopping and then running again immediately)
- tried to force stop the scheduler from powershell (hangs forever)
- tried to force stop the service on the server (hangs forever then errors out)

No windows updates have been applied in the last week and no one has touched the sync service on the server for over a month.

Event logs aren't providing any information at all other than ProvisioningServiceAdapter::ExecuteWithRetry: Action: ImportV1 will be retried after 00:00:15. Attempt 0 of 5.

Is there any way to force stop this service beyond what I have tried? Anyone else experiencing this problem?

[Sync Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4yQF.png)

Comment: What is the error when you force stop the service on the server?

Comment: `it's with a change to the ADSYNC account` Do you mean you change the password of Azure AD Connect sync service account password?

Answer (score 0):

If you run Azure AD Connect in configuration mode the synchronizations will stop.

Comment: The only way I could get the Configuration tool to run is by attempting to stop the AD service, setting it to Manual start and rebooting the VM. But this still doesn't fix the issue, even if I rebuild the config.

As soon as it gets to the import to azure stage, it sits there until next sync cycle.

Comment: If you double click the Azure AD Connect shortcut on the desktop that was created when you installed Azure AD Connect it should stop the synchronization automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the service to prevent it from trying to recover after forcibly killing it, but you can forcibly stop the service with some powershell.

```
Stop-process -ID $(Get-WmiObject -Class win32_service -Filter "name = 'ADSync'").processid
```

Answer (score 0):

You can kill the service executable from the Task Manager; at this point, I don't think it's going to do any more harm.

In the Services MMC, you can look at the service properties and find the executable name (sorry, I don't have an ADConnect server available right now). You should also configure the service as "disabled" before killing its process, so you'll be sure it doesn't restart automatically.